# Display DataTable object in C# MVC AngularJS

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I have an action that returns DataTable object (recieved by sql query on the database)
Since its the result of an open query, it doesnt necessarily relates to a model, so I cant retrieve Lost and iterate on it in ng-repeat.
I want to present the DataTable as it is in the page, is there any way to do so?

Comment: look up nggrid and how to use it... lots of examples out there

Comment: @MethodMan Thanks, I got it